# How to monitor jvm heap size with Pyspark / Dataproc

Tags: pyspark, heap-memory, py4j

I have noticed my pyspark codes are causing memory out of error. Using VirtualVM, I have noticed points where heap size increases over the executor memory, and changed the codes. Now that I am trying to deploy codes with bigger data and in dataproc, I found it hard to find a good way to monitor the heap size. Is there any good way to monitor the runtime heap size? I think It would be easiest if I can print out the runtime heap size via py4j or any other libraries.